# Changing contents of a std::string with a function

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I feel like this answer will be quick and simple, but I cannot seem to figure it out right now.

```
 #include <string>
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 void change_thing (string x) {
      x="not thing";
 }
 int main() {
     string maybe_thing;
     maybe_thing="thing";
     change_thing(maybe_thing);
     cout << maybe_thing << endl;
     return 0;
 }
```

I **want** `maybe_thing` to be "not thing" when it prints. I've tried a bunch of different pointer strategies, but nothing seems to work (which I could easily just be doing wrong; my knowledge of pointers is incomplete anyway because I'm new to c++).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change `void change_thing (string x)` to `void change_thing (string &x)` so you pass by reference. Currently you are modifying a local copy in the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a pointer, just [pass the string by reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/):

```
void change_thing (string & x) {
    x="not thing";
}
```

Comment: Well, I guess it was that easy. Thanks!